# MacPro 5,1 1333 MHz RAM Spec

Tags: memory, mac-pro

I have a question concerning the memory spec for my Mac Pro. This Mac is originally a Mac Pro 4,1 with flashed firmware to Model 5,1. The CPUs are 2x [Intel x5690](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52576/intel-xeon-processor-x5690-12m-cache-3-46-ghz-6-40-gt-s-intel-qpi.html). Now I would like to upgrade the memory. I ordered 8x16GB [SK Hynix RAM HMT42GR7CMR4C-H9](https://www.skhynix.com/eolproducts.view.do?pronm=DDR3%20SDRAM&srnm=HMT42GR7CMR4C&rk=20&rc=module) on eBay.

I expected my Mac to recognise it as 1333 MHz memory. Instead it is recognised as 800 MHz Memory when all 8 Memory Modules are plugged in.

Thus I did a little research. [According to Mac Rumors Forum](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/48-gb-ram-1333-mhz-in-flashed-mac-pro-5-1-working-as-1066-mhz.1462350/) quad-rank could be a problem. On the other hand there is also [quad-rank memory sold on ebay specifically for mac pro 4,1/5,1](https://www.ebay.de/itm/128GB-1333MHz-RAM-Kit-8x-16GB-Memory-Upgrade-Apple-Mac-Pro-4-1-5-1-Server/162944185863?hash=item25f03af607:g:BlQAAOSwzwpdk4o1).

Furthermore I tried the following:

- Populating slots 1-3 and 5-7 (Numbering according to [Apple docs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205043#1)) with the RAM modules.
  That resulted in 1066 MHz memory speed
- Populating Slot 1 & 5
  That also resulted in 1066 MHz memory speed
- Populating Slots 1-3 and 5-7 with [SK Hynix HMT351R7EFR4A-H9](https://www.skhynix.com/eolproducts.view.do?pronm=DDR3+SDRAM&srnm=HMT351R7EFR4A&rk=20&rc=module) Memory, wich should be single-ranked. But still 1066 MHz.

All this does not really makes a consistent picture to me. So my question is:

**On what does it depend whether 1333 MHz memory runs at full speed on my Mac Pro?**

What is the limiting criterion? Is there a list of fully supported memory? Does it make sense to force my Mac to run the memory at 1333 MHz and if yes: is there a way to do so?

---

**Edit**

I am running latest 10.14, the latest officially supported MacOS for MacPro 5,1.

Comment: Despite the lower clock which can happen for quite a few reasons including [placement of other ram _(assuming it’s all in spec and operating properly)_](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299170/2009), how is memory constraining your workload? I would always add more RAM over having less run higher rate.

Comment: Actually it's a hobby project to max out this old cheese grater. So no specific work load.

Comment: What OS is on it? I heard the requirements changed in more recent OSes, but I've only got 64GB in mine [8x8] so never been near the 96 in triple channel vs 128 in quadruple issue. btw, if you're only populating 2 slots, it should be 1 & 2.

Comment: My Mac runs the latest officially supported OS for MacPro 5,1. I updated my initial post accordingly.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm not sure I can be of much more help - the firmware update you did to install Mojave is the one that allows 128GB; the limiting factor for speed should be the CPU, for which the ones you have eminently qualify. I don't have sufficient knowledge as regards specific RAM chips, sorry.